# Using Euclidean Loss together with the softmax

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using the following code as loss function. This is the Euclidean loss.

```
def euc_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    lx = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_true[:, :] - y_pred[:, :]), axis=1, keepdims=True))
    return (150 * lx)
```

How can I use Euclidean loss together with that of the softmax so I do get the score?

Comment: Are you looking for creating a custom metric? https://keras.io/api/metrics/

Comment: I think yes.. I would like to get the confidence rate along with the prediction output so I want to combine both softmax and euclidean loss

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand but one thing you could do is use euc_loss for training and then once that's done, if you want the softmax output, you can append a softmax layer to the end of your model for evaluation.

Comment: @MZ I added the softmax activation as  `cls2_fc_pose_xyz = Dense(3, name='cls2_fc_pose_xyz', activation='softmax')(cls2_fc1)` but for some reason, I'm still not getting the confidence rate when I predict :(

Comment: Did you make sure to set that as your output layer for your model when predicting? And you can also just do a `Activation(softmax)`, when you provide a new Dense layer, the weights can affect the output in an unpredicted manner

Comment: yes this is my model output definition `Model(input=input, output=[cls2_fc_pose_xyz])`

Comment: can you post what your output was and what your expected output is? And again try using `Activation('softmax')`